# How to determine $(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])^{\times}$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{2p}$ with $p \equiv -3 \ [8]$ and we define :

$\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]=\{a+b\alpha\ / a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]=\{a+b\alpha\ / a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Let $N : \mathbb{Q}[\alpha] \to \mathbb{Q},\ a+b\alpha\mapsto \vert a^2 -2pb^2 \vert$, a multiplicative map for $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$.

I have to show that : $(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])^{\times}=\{u\in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\ / N(u)=1\}$.

Let $u \in (\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])^{\times}$ so there exists $v \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ such as : $uv=1$. Taking the map $N$ we obtain : $N(uv)=N(u)N(v)=1$.

To conclude I must have $N(u)=1$ but the problem is that $N$ takes value en $\mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm of a quadratic integer, as of any element in a  number field which is integral over $\mathbf Z$, is an integer, since the norm is the product of all conjugates of that element, which has a monic polynomial in $\mathbf Z[x]$ as its minimal  polynomial.

Comment: That means for $v \in \mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ we have $N(v)=1$ ?

Comment: For $v\in \mathbf Z[\alpha]^{\color{red}\times}$, we have $N(v)=1$ or $-1$.